# Finding Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix: $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}. $$
I found the eigen values $$\lambda_1=1-\sqrt{5} \\\text{and} \\ \lambda_2=1+\sqrt{5}.$$
But for some reason when I try to find the eigenvectors I keep getting that $$\begin{bmatrix} 1-(1-\sqrt{5}) & 1 \\ 1 & -1+\sqrt{5}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ reduces to $$\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{5} & 1 \\ 0 & -4+\sqrt{5}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ but then that would mean my eigenvector would be $$V_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Which cant be true.

Comment: The roots should be halved. You forgot the "over $2a$" portion of the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$$

Because

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$A-\lambda I=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1-\lambda & 1 \\
        1 & -\lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(1-\lambda)(-\lambda)-1\cdot1$$
$$=\lambda^2-\lambda-1$$